# PHPUnit StackTest::assertEmpty() deprecated

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am learning building php unit tests using [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) . There they have a manual and I encountered this [example](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.examples.StackTest2.php) Where they use assertEmpty(), but when I run this code in command line I get this error : `Call to undefined method StackTest::assertEmpty() in /var/www/.../tests/StackTest.php on line 20`. So if this method is deprecated or something why they use it , also is there another method for this? (of course I can try this `$this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));`) but anyways...
The same with `assertNotEmpty()`.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Same problem here problem here

Comment: You need to use phpunit >=3.5 && <=3.8 https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-4.0.0#backwards-compatibility-issues

Answer (score 7):

I'm on debian, and it looks like the default install of PHPunit is a bit old (3.4.14).

If you search for "assertEmpty" in this url, you will see what version it was added in (3.5.0-1).
http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/p/phpunit/phpunit_3.6.10-1/changelog.html

What worked for me was removing phpunit from the system with apt, and installing it with pear
http://www.santiagolizardo.com/article/how-to-install-pear-and-phpunit-in-debianubuntu/57001

These links also helped me.
["Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addfiletofilter() in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 48"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241183/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-phpunit-util-filteraddfiletofilter-in)

[Cannot get PHPunit working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078707/cannot-get-phpunit-working)

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the unit test from the command line with the [phpunit command line tools](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html)?

```
phpunit --verbose StackTest stacktest.php
```

Comment: Any luck yet? Perhaps just go with 'phpunit name_of_your_file.php'

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, it also errors if you use assertCount()