# Cannot get PHPunit working

Tags: php, phpunit

I have been tring to get PHPunit working for my zend framework project and have been encountering various problems. I have reinstalled PEAR and uninstalled PHPunit, and reinstalled them both.

My current error is

> demian@dimbo-TP:~$ phpunit
>   PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php/:/usr/local/share/php/library') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48

I am using ubuntu 11.10, PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.2

I would be very grateful if someone could give me some pointers. I have looked plenty on google, but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Thanks,

Demian.

Here is my shell dump which shows what I have done recently:

```
demian@dimbo-TP:~$ phpunit
The program 'phpunit' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install phpunit

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
[sudo] password for demian:  

Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is already initialized

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is already initialized

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no

Channel "components.ez.no" is already initialized

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear update-channels

Updating channel "components.ez.no"

Channel "components.ez.no" is up to date

Updating channel "doc.php.net"

Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date

Updating channel "pear.php.net"

Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date

Updating channel "pear.phpunit.de"

Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is up to date

Updating channel "pear.symfony-project.com"

Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is up to date

Updating channel "pecl.php.net"

Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear upgrade-all

Will upgrade channel://pear.php.net/benchmark

downloading Benchmark-1.2.8.tgz ...

Starting to download Benchmark-1.2.8.tgz (8,352 bytes)

.....done: 8,352 bytes

upgrade-all ok: channel://pear.php.net/Benchmark-1.2.8

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit

downloading PHPUnit-3.6.3.tgz ...

Starting to download PHPUnit-3.6.3.tgz (116,362 bytes)

.........................done: 116,362 bytes

install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.3

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage

phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.1

install failed

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ phpunit


PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php): failed to open 
stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 
'PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php/:/usr/local/share/php/library') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ pear install phpunit

Warning: lstat(): Lstat failed for /tmp/pear/cache/312d32445ed39d8611ead5ee1d8cd72frest.cacheid in PEAR/REST.php on line 276
PHP Warning:  lstat(): Lstat failed for /tmp/pear/cache/312d32445ed39d8611ead5ee1d8cd72frest.cacheid in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 276
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/phpunit"
install failed

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear install phpunit

WARNING: "pear/PHPUnit" is deprecated in favor of "phpunit/PHPUnit"
Did not download dependencies: pear/PHP_Compat, use --alldeps or --onlyreqdeps to download automatically
pear/PHPUnit can optionally use package "pear/PHP_Compat"
downloading PHPUnit-1.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-1.3.2.tgz (20,913 bytes)
........done: 20,913 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/PHPUnit-1.3.2

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ phpunit

PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php/:/usr/local/share/php/library') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear uninstall phpunit
uninstall ok: channel://pear.php.net/PHPUnit-1.3.2

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ ^C

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.6.3
install failed

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ phpunit

PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php/:/usr/local/share/php/library') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ pear install --force phpunit/PHPUnit

WARNING: configuration download directory "/tmp/pear/download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pear.phpunit.de" is not writeable by the current user

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit

phpunit/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.6.3
install failed

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ pear install --force phpunit/PHPUnit

WARNING: configuration download directory "/tmp/pear/download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pear.phpunit.de" is not writeable by the current user

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ sudo pear install --force phpunit/PHPUnit

Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
downloading PHPUnit-3.6.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.6.3.tgz (116,362 bytes)
.........................done: 116,362 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.3

demian@dimbo-TP:~$ phpunit

PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php/:/usr/local/share/php/library') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48
```

Comment: For not writable error see php.ini (line 988) [Phar]; http://php.net/phar.readonly;phar.readonly = Off

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It picks up the right phpunit but the other packages are missing. You should be able to fix this using

```
sudo pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/phpunit
```

or if you want to only update the lib that seems to be the issue:

```
sudo pear install --force phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject
```

**Windows Users:** Omit "sudo"if you are on windows platform

Comment: Fixed it using :sudo pear install --force phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject

Comment: what a stupid error.  why does it not install mockobject as a dependency?  thanks for this, anyway!

Comment: This was a solution for my problem in NetBeans:PHPUnit version too old! thanks

Comment: This should be in the official PHPUnit docs. Every time I install PHPUnit I end up here!

Comment: I had to use `pear install --alldeps --force pear.phpunit.de/DbUnit`