# Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_iterator_autoload()

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

We are developping a Symfony2 project on which we wrote several PHPUnit tests.

On some of them (the ones involving large memmory ammounts) we get an error message:

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) GapCoach\Bundle\Tests\Controller\ClientControllerTest::testDesaClient
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_iterator_autoload() in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/GlobalState.php on line 379

I installed the last PHPUnit version, and `file_iterator_autoload` function really exists and is accessible.

How can we solve this error?

Comment: Can it [solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700642/fatal-error-file-iterator-autoload-php-not-found-when-running-phpunit)?

Comment: No. PhpUnit is working correctly. We have about 50 Test classes and it only fails on 5...

Comment: Which PHPUnit and PHP version is that? This could be a problem, see  https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/683

Comment: "PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann." and "PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies"

Comment: It seems that with PHPUnit 3.7 it should be solved... I'll try to upgrade my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was just to upgrade PHPUnit to version **3.7.13**

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a machine that for one reason or another can not be immediately upgraded to have PHP 5.3.3 or above (which PHPUnit 3.7 [requires](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)), then you can fix this error by downgrading packages.

`pear list -a` should produce something like:

```
Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
============================================
Package            Version State
File_Iterator      1.3.3   stable
PHPUnit            3.6.12  stable
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.1   stable
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.4   stable
PHP_Timer          1.0.4   stable
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.4   stable
Text_Template      1.1.2   stable
```

You need the 1.3.2 version of File_Iterator, the 1.1.1 version of Text_Template, and the 1.0.3 version of PHP_Timer.

So uninstall the old:

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject
pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
pear uninstall phpunit/File_Iterator
pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_Timer
pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_TokenStream
pear uninstall phpunit/Text_Template
```

You should be able to verify that you have no phpunit packages installed:

```
pear list -a
Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
============================================
(no packages installed)
```

Now explicitly install these dependency versions first:

```
pear install phpunit/File_Iterator-1.3.2
pear install phpunit/PHP_Timer-1.0.3
pear install phpunit/Text_Template-1.1.1
```

Then PHPUnit:

```
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit

pear list -a
Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
============================================
Package            Version State
File_Iterator      1.3.2   stable
PHPUnit            3.6.12  stable
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.1   stable
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.4   stable
PHP_Invoker        1.1.2   stable
PHP_Timer          1.0.3   stable
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.4   stable
Text_Template      1.1.1   stable
```

All should work now : )