# "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addfiletofilter() in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 48"

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, command-line-interface, php

I have just installed phpunit using PEAR on our Ubuntu/Linux server
( Linux mccoy 2.6.28-11-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 02:45:36 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux )

when I try to run a unit test I get the error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addfiletofilter() in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 48"

I have googled this and came across a few threads on it however none of these seem to fix my issue.

I have added the following line to my

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:

include_path = ".:/usr/share/php/PHPUnit"
```

(I've also tried it without the "/PHPUnit" folder included)

But I still get this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

gvanto

edit: this is what is in start of file /user/bin/phpunit:

```
// ...just comments prior to this

 if (extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
     xdebug_disable(); }

 if (strpos('/usr/bin/php', '@php_bin') === 0) {
     set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()); }

 require_once 'PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php';

 PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addFileToFilter(__FILE__, 'PHPUNIT'); //line 48

 require 'PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php';

 define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone else having this problem, i just commented this line out as a last ditch attempt to fix it and phpuni doesn't seem to complain (so far)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a version conflict / installation issue.

`pear version` should produce `1.9.4.`. If not `pear upgrade` and follow the commands until it does.

Then `sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit` to fix the installation.+

Your include path should include the "pear" dir. Use `pear config-show` to find that.